# What is the name of the song playing in Fullmetal Alchemist (2003) in episode 6 at 21:07

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series

I've been looking for this song for years, tried looking through the entire soundtrack and just haven't found it. This is from the original Full Metal Alchemist series which aired in 2003. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Awkwardly, found the song almost immediately after posting. The song is

Full Metal Alchemist OST 1 - Title

dunno how to remove questions.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Looks like you found the answer by yourself, and great! Stack Exchange encourages to [self-answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) their own questions because it can also help future readers. No need to delete it :)